# PHP - Link to local file

Tags: php

How can I link to a local file in PHP?

I've tried all of these, but nothing works to prompt a file-download.

According to:  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

I can add:  file:///

But my editor doesn't like that when I also add the \ to designate the folder-structure, and the page then fails to load.

```
$path = "file:\\\E:\machine\files\months\";
$path = "file:\\\E:\\machine\\files\\months\\";
$path = "file:\\\E:/\machine/\files/\months/\";
$path = "file:\\\E:/machine/files/months/";
```

None of those work -- either the page fails to load, or the slashes aren't going the correct direction for local paths.

How can I link to a file on a local machine? (*yes I know it will only work if the path structure is exactly the same*)

Thanks

EDIT -- The issue isn't the filename.  I add that later and that works fine.  The issue is my syntax with path AND/OR file:///

My editor complains about file:///
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4lRI.jpg

Comment: In all of those cases, you still need the actual file name at the end of the path. E.G. `$path = "file://E:/machine/files/months/download_file.pdf"` Is that being added later in the script?

Comment: Yes, the filename is added later on and that works correctly.  The problem is my syntax with the direct path.  As I said, either my slashes aren't added correctly, or the page fails to load.  My issue is not related to the filename.

Comment: What you posted doesn't work either.  My editor complains about "file://"   or "file:///"    See:  http://imgur.com/uEaxgnM

Comment: Ok, your editor is complaining, but does the code work?  You might try single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I've tried single quotes and double quotes.  Here is a screenshot of the code, and then of the result in Mozilla.  Look at the Mozilla view.  The slashes are going the wrong way regardless of the direction I put them in the code:  http://imgur.com/4kSGgLj    Slashes for a local path need to go \  not /

Comment: Or you can just learn something new.... Danged direction of slashes apparently doesn't matter.  "Doh!"  In all my years using a PC, I never knew Windows could interpret local paths with the forward slash.  Dang...      Thanks